# Spring Data Cassandra: "No property findAll for type User"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I have a very simple spring data cassandra project for which the application context fails to startup. The entire project consists of four files: a domain object, a repository interface, the cassandra configuration, and an application entry point. Here is the domain object:

```
@Table
public class User {
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "user_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    public UUID userId;
}
```

and the repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, UUID> {
}
```

The configuration is pretty simple:

```
@Configuration
public class TestSpringDataCassandraConfiguration extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {
    @Override 
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "company";
    }
    @Override 
    protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {
        return Collections.singletonList(CreateKeyspaceSpecification
                .createKeyspace(getKeyspaceName())
                .ifNotExists()
                .withSimpleReplication(1));
    }
    @Override 
    public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
        return new String[] { "com.company.project.cassandra.entity"};
    }
    @Override 
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

And the entry point is as simple as it can get.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] sa) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, sa);
    }
}
```

Here are the project dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Despite all of this, the application fails to start up with the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type User!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at com.company.project.Application.main(Application.java:9) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type User!
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:247) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:378) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.PartTreeCassandraQuery.<init>(PartTreeCassandraQuery.java:47) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.CassandraRepositoryFactory$CassandraQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(CassandraRepositoryFactory.java:163) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.CassandraRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CassandraRepositoryFactoryBean.java:76) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        ... 15 common frames omitted
```

The really weird thing is that the application starts up just fine if the `UserRepository` extends a `CrudRepository`. Does anyone have any idea what is wrong with this set up?

Comment: Spring Data for Apache Cassandra does not support `PagingAndSortingRepository`. Use just `CrudRepository`.

Comment: What? Yes it does. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts

Comment: You're referring to the generic documentation part explain how repositories work in general (`This chapter explains the core concepts and interfaces of Spring Data repositories. The information in this chapter is pulled from the Spring Data Commons module. It uses the configuration and code samples for the Java Persistence API (JPA) module.`).

Comment: Welp, that isn't confusing in the slightest. Nowhere in the documentation does it say that paging can't be used. Do you know if count methods are supported? I'm also having issues with those. Go ahead and add an answer; thank you for your help.

Comment: Count is supported via count() but not count projections (`countByFirstnameandLastname(…)`). Care to post a new question with your count issue?

Comment: Nope, we decided to ditch spring data due to the lack of support for paging (which the datastax driver provides)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making @mp911de's comment into a proper answer:

> Spring Data for Apache Cassandra does not support `PagingAndSortingRepository`. Use just `CrudRepository`.

Unfortunately, the reference documentation mentions features as support for `PagingAndSortingRepository` but that is just the general part about how Spring Data works.

There are plans to work on an improvement of the documentation: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1086

Comment: Adding to this with a note from the official documentation: `Cassandra repositories do not extend PagingAndSortingRepository, because classic paging patterns using limit/offset are not applicable to Cassandra.`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra-repo-usage